# qmap unicode qstring not working

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qmap

Im trying to use a mapping from language names into local
filenames, for example:

```
QMap<QString, QString> map;
map.insert("Русский", "russian");
```

Yet when I dump out the values, it comes out null:

```
QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator it = map.begin();
while (it != map.end())
{
    qDebug() << "Language: " << it.key();
    ++it;
}

Language: ""
```

Ive tried to set the QTextCodec as follows:

```
QTextCodec * codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(codec);
m_langMap.insert(codec->fromUnicode("Русский"), "russian");
```

Yet same results.  What am I doing wrong here?  I really need this map to
use in several places without replicating code.

Thanks

== EDIT ==

Sorry, thought I was editing my own.  Here's non-working code, about identical to
the short sample I made that works.  The work-file is a much much larger file.

in CTOR:

```
m_ui->setupUi(this);

m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"English"), "english");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Dansk"), "dansk");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Nederlands"), "dutch");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Čeština"), "czeck");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Slovenský"), "slovak");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Magyar"), "hungarian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Român"), "romanian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Latviešu"), "latvian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Lietuvių"), "lithuanian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Polski"), "polish");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Português"), "portuguese");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Español"), "spanish");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Français"), "french");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Italiano"), "italian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Svenska"), "swedish");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Русский"), "russian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Українська"), "ukranian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Русский"), "russian");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"中文"), "chinese");
m_langMap.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"日本語"), "japanese");

QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator it = m_langMap.begin();
while (it != m_langMap.end())
{
    m_form.language_combo->addItem(it.key());
    ++it;
}
```

== EDIT 2 ===

I created a new question here:

[Unicode characters in qt app dont show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776921/unicode-characters-in-qt-app-dont-show-up)

Comment: Don't forget to save source file as UTF-8 or in 1251 code page. This works for me, if I save source file with 1251 encoding (Windows Cyrillic).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
map.insert(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Русский"), "russian");
```

**Edit:**

Using QStringList works too:

```
QStringList sl;
sl << QString::fromWCharArray(L"Русский")
   << QString::fromWCharArray(L"English")
   << QString::fromWCharArray(L"日本語");
ui->comboBox->addItems(sl);
```

Comment: Thanks Roku, what does the L do there?  And is there a way to print it back out using qDebug()?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to set codepage for your command prompt with `chcp` command.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810343/is-a-wide-character-string-literal-starting-with-l-like-lhello-world-guarantee

Comment: Ok Im still not finding the answer on this.  Im using a Linux machine.  After I insert it into a map I need to add it to a Combo box and thats not working (Its not coming out as expected).  How do I do this?

Comment: This works in my Linux machine: `ui->comboBox->addItem(QString::fromWCharArray(L"Русский"));` Is your source code file saved using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: yes.  Very odd.  I setup another single small qt project to test this and its definitely UTF-8.  My UTF-8 BOM is 'keep if already present', same results, I get blank entries.

Comment: ah nevermind, I was trying to do a QStringList inserting those.  Turns out inserting them directly works.  Is there a way to use a QStringList to iterate over them?

Comment: BOM shouldn't matter in the UTF-8 encoding. QStringList works fine for me, I edited the answer for that. Maybe you should show your nonworking code.

Comment: It would be better to add the additional information to your question than to my answer.